# Magento template is not being rendered

Tags: magento, templates, layout, block

I'm trying to debug ”Search Autocomplete and Suggest” extension on my system. it works fine on one store but not on another installation.

The template for the results is not being rendered. the block is extending Mage_Core_Block_Template and when im adding debug print to the block's _prepareLayout() its being displayed correctly.

The parent template (blank.phtml) is rendered correctly, but nothing is displayed from the child template (suggest.phtml), no matter what its content is.

Here is the parent template code (blank.phtml):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

and the layout update:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <searchautocomplete_suggest_result>
        <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>searchautocomplete/blank.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="searchautocomplete/suggest" name="searchautocomplete" template="searchautocomplete/suggest.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </searchautocomplete_suggest_result>
</layout>
```

Im testing it with this url:

```
/index.php/searchautocomplete/suggest/result/?q=something
```

What can be the problem?

---

**Update**

After installing another copy of my store and adding my customizations, this extension seems to work fine. 
I will try to compare the old installation vs the new one and post my findings.

Comment: Are you see the Ajax request/response in your firebug???

Comment: can you go to searchautocomplete/suggest/result and debug this action?

Comment: No debbugger, but i can add test messages there

Comment: I don't have that extension handy, but if you'd like to post some more code snippets, it could help.  Post the controller as well as your custom blocks.

Comment: The controller action is only calling loadLayout() and renderLayout(), the block code is too long to post, but even if i remove all the block methods the template still doesnt load.  Here is a link to the extension files: http://freegento.com/magento-extensions/Searchautocomplete-0.0.11.tgz

Comment: It seems to work fine on a new installation. i will try to find the reason and update.

Comment: you're sure your blank.phtml rendered correctly? how do you know? did you echo other things (other than getchildhtml content)?

Comment: Yes, i`m able to see the output of echos from the blank.html template but not from the suggest.html template. On my new installation it works fine.

Comment: put this code in your blank.phtml echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->asString())."</pre>"; it will print your loaded layout xml, post it in here

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::asStrinâ€Œâ€‹g() in ***/app/design/frontend/default/theme040k/template/searchautocomplete/blank.phtml on line 1

Comment: Please pay attention with the copy-paste thing. Did you notice there was 'weird' character between character n and g in `Strin g`

Comment: Sorry, there were some hidden chars pasted. here is the layout xml: http://pastebin.com/bCL45LhG

Comment: One more thing, have you do `inspect element`. Just to make sure <ul class="ajaxsearch" ><li style="display:none"></li> is not being rendered

Comment: Yes, no response at all unless im echoing something in blank.phtml itself.